# The application has failed to start because python33.dll was not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-2005

I am working on project by using boost python and visual studio 2005. when i debug a simple hello world example the  folowing error window appear.
**The application has failed to start because python33.dll was not found.Reinstalling the application may fix this problem**

Can somebody please tell its error on Python or on windows regisrty.Beacause i reinstall Python but error is still there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Removing this error set the environoment varaible for both Python and also for Boost Python by folowing ways.

1.Right click on the project and select Properties.

2.Inside the Configuration Properties ,select Debugging and  set the Environment  with   Python 3 and Boost Python 1_54 with following commands

```
   **PATH=%PATH%;c:\python33;C:\boost_1_54_0\stage\lib**
```